# mongoddb :How to read binary files in chunks with c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am able to save a binary file in mongodb server through following code:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\Data_w.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var gridFsInfo = database.GridFS.Upload(fs, fileName);
}
```

I can see the file saved in server. The file is about 42MB in size. I want to read the file in  chunks i.e. read once chunk at a time and deserialize the binary data and flush to browser.

How can I read the data in chunks from mongodb through c# driver?

As per my understanding following commandline reads only 0th chunk from the big file:

db.fs.chunks.find({"files_id" : ObjectId("53f74e2f3f69bd30142f2193"),"n":0})

but dont know how to write same in c#. Please help

Comment: Why you think that you can deserialize the part of the file?

Comment: its because the binary file  contains serialized data.

Comment: even if I dont have to deserialze how shall i read the contents in chunks. I know that GridFS saves larger file (>16MB) in chunks. I want to read same thing in chunks. How Shall I?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file GridFS.Open(string remoteFileName, FileMode mode) that returns MongoGridFSStream and use it like any other System.IO.Stream. It doesn't download chunks that you don't use and buffers chunks for you, so there is no need to concern yourself with implementation. So you can just read a part of stream, flush to browser, read another, flush and so on.

Documentation for C# driver is lacking, [source code is the best documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver).